# Localization of .net core 2 exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core, msxml

Is it possible to give .net core 2.0 exceptions in a specific language? And how is it done? I cannot find any language packs for .net core 2.0

This is especially usefull for XML validation exceptions.

Comment: There's nothing *worse* than localized exception messages. They are meaningless to end users and make googling an error message impossible. Shouldn't you be looking for ways to localize your application's messages?

Comment: I've updated the question with an usage description. In .NET Core 4 Exceptions are multiling (after adding language packs). It is indeed ugly but.. sometimes usefull

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I also need XML validation exceptions, they are pretty good and self-describing.

Comment: Is this a WebApi application?